# How to change the value of a field in Django after a while?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a user model and I just added a premium field in it, now I want after expiration_date expired, the value of is_premium to change to False and, expiration_date and premium_time to change to none or something like that

My user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    PREMIUM_TIME_CHOICES = (
        (1, "1 Month"),
        (3, "3 Month"),
        (6, "6 Month"),
        (12, "12 Month")
    )

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    expiration_date  = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    premium_time = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, choices=PREMIUM_TIME_CHOICES, max_length=1)
```

My siganls:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=account_models.User)
def add_premium_time(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_premium:
        expiration_date = timezone.now() + timezone.timedelta(days=(instance.premium_time * 30))
        instance.expiration_date = expiration_date
        instance.save()
```

Comment: What is the current issue that you are facing? Is it a logical issue?

Comment: Based on what you described it looks like you need a `scheduled job` to verify `expiration_date` field of each user.

Comment: After the is_premium field changed to True, expiration_date is set, then I want that when the current time reaches the expiration_date, is_premium change to False but I don't know if cron can do this or not because cron classes run after the time that given

Answer (score 0):

When I need to run functions on a regular basis I use Django Crons to do it automatically. [https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/]

Comment: I am familiar with this, for example exactly after the is_premium field changed to True, expiration_date is set, then I want that when the current time reaches the expiration_date, is_premium change to False, but using cron doesn't do that because cron classes run after the time that given. I don't know if cron can do this or not

Comment: @nima_sh I have cronjobs that run every night after midnight to find end_dates and change the status of what we call campaigns and schedules. When employees log in after the cronjob has run they see the changes to the campaign and schedule end_date. Would something like that work for this?

Comment: No actually, because this is for the premium time in my app, when the user purchases the premium pack, I get and save the premium time that the user purchased (like 1 month); then in the expiration_date  field, I add the current time to 1 month then save it. now I want when the current time reaches the expiration_date, the is_premium field changed to False